# Yii Po file importer - plurals

Tags: php, yii, gettext, po

How can I add support for plural forms in this Yii class:

http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.8/framework/i18n/gettext/CGettextPoFile.php

?

Right now the pattern is

```
     $pattern='/(msgctxt\s+"(.*?(?<!\\\\))")?'
            . '\s+msgid\s+"(.*?(?<!\\\\))"'
            . '\s+msgstr\s+"(.*?(?<!\\\\))"/';
```

which corresponds to something like this (inside the po file):

```
msgid "Edit Comments"
msgstr "Modifier les commentaires"
```

But a plural definition looks like this:

```
msgid "%s comment"
msgid_plural "%s comments"
msgstr[0] "%s commentaire"
msgstr[1] "%s commentaires"
```

The problem is that depending on the language, there can be msgstr[3], msgstr[4] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it better to look for a PHP gettext library that already has plurals and msgctx support.